# build type isn't jni debuggable error

Tags: android, android-ndk

i want to debug c++ ndk with android studio but 
when i create a "Android Native" run configuration, I get the error "Build type isn't jni debuggable".
my build.gradle :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.amk.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


        ndk {
            moduleName "HelloJNI"
        }
        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }
        task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', 'main','NDK_DEBUG=1'
            } else {
                commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
            }
        }

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            ndk {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

my configuration:

[image]

i can run c++ ndk but cant debug that

what i can do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For starters, I'm using Android Studio 1.5 / gradle 2.8

**I fixed this by changing my `build.gradle` to**

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debuggable = true
            }

        }
        debug {
            debuggable = true
            jniDebuggable = true
        }

    }
```

So, basically, I just added the lines

```
ndk {
        debuggable = true
}
```

To release, and

```
debug {
         debuggable = true
         jniDebuggable = true
}
```

To the enclosing `buildTypes`

**But this syntax varies, based on your gradle version. Look [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/42) and [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/20) for help with other gradle versions**

Comment: `jniDebuggable` is not valid in gradle-experimental for NDK builds.